# A intersection interior of B is a subset of interior of B relative to A

Tags: general-topology

I was able to prove that $A \cap int(B) \subseteq int_A (B)$ but I wasn't able to show the opposite direction.

Please help me.
If $int_A(B)\nsubseteq A\cap int(B)$, what condition is required for it to be true?

I need the condition to be based on general topology.

Answer (score 1):

Equality does not hold in general.  Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  Note that $\mathrm{Int}_{\mathbb{R}} ( \mathbb{Q} ) \cap \mathbb{Q} = \varnothing \cap \mathbb{Q} = \varnothing$, however $\mathrm{Int}_{\mathbb{Q}} ( \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathbb{Q}$.

Equality holds for all $B \subseteq A$ iff $A$ is itself an open subset of $X$.  (If $A$ is open in $X$, then the open subsets of the subspace $A$ are just the open subsets of $X$ which are subsets of $A$. If $A$ is not open in $X$, compare $\mathrm{Int}_X ( A ) \cap A$ and $\mathrm{Int}_A ( A )$.)